# bash, how to select three fields of a file separated by space and then other fields separated by another sign?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file in this format:

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee|fff|ggg|hhh|iii|lll|mmm|nnn|ooo|ppp
aaa1 bbb1 ccc1 ddd1 eee1|fff1|ggg1|hhh1|iii1|lll1|mmm1|nnn1|ooo1|ppp1
aaa2 bbb2 ccc2 ddd2 eee2|fff2|ggg2|hhh2|iii2|lll2|mmm2|nnn2|ooo2|ppp2
```

As you can see, the first three fields are separated by a space, while the other ones are separated by the | sign.
I would like to select the first 3 fields, and then the 8th and 9th fields.

I would like to have the following output:

```
aaa bbb ccc hhh iii
aaa1 bbb1 ccc1 hhh1 iii1
aaa2 bbb2 ccc2 hhh2 iii2
```

As you can see, I should filter on **two delimiters**: space and pipe.

**How can I do in on bash?**

I tried with `awk` but I was unable to run it with two different delimiters.

Comment: Is the total number of fields fixed?

Comment: Have you tried using a character class as field separator? Like `-F '[ |]`?

Comment: You can replace pipes with spaces or vice-versa and then split the line using one delimiter.

Comment: BTW, `IFS=' |' read -a words` will read your whole line into the array `words`, treating *either* pipes or spaces as delimiters the whole way through. My own answer takes a more cautious approach, treating spaces as special *only* in the first pipe-delimited field.

Comment: The question begs the question: is `a|b b|b c|c ddd eee|f f|g g|h h` a valid/expected line of input?  Or are `|` and ` ` known to not be present except where expected?

Comment: How about just running each line through `tr '|' ' '`?  So the whole thing would be `cat file.txt | tr '|' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 1-3,8,9`

Answer (score 2):

If your code isn't so performance-sensitive as to make awk a better choice, the below does the parsing in question in native bash, and does so in such a way as to have correct results even if pipe-separated fields other than the first contain spaces:

```
while IFS='|' read -r -a psep_fields; do          # read into pipe-separated fields
  read -r -a space_fields <<<"${psep_fields[0]}"  # read 1st field & parse by spaces
  printf '%s %s %s %s %s\n' \
    "${space_fields[0]}" "${space_fields[1]}" "${space_fields[2]}" \
    "${psep_fields[3]}" "${psep_fields[4]}"
done
```

See this running on your input at https://ideone.com/zCjpDP, returning as output:

```
aaa bbb ccc hhh iii
aaa1 bbb1 ccc1 hhh1 iii1
aaa2 bbb2 ccc2 hhh2 iii2
```

Comment: ...if that's permissible. We really need a formal spec for the format.

Answer (score 2):

If your input may have pipe in first 4 fields or spaces in piped string then better to use this `awk` that splits 5th field using `|` as delimiter:

```
awk 'NF>3{s = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3; sub(/^[ \t]*([^ \t]+[ \t]+){4}/, "");
if (split($0, a, "|") > 4) s = s OFS a[4] OFS a[5]; print s}' file
```

```
aaa bbb ccc hhh iii
aaa1 bbb1 ccc1 hhh1 iii1
aaa2 bbb2 ccc2 hhh2 iii2
```

Comment: ...if, of course, spaces are actively disallowed in all but the first pipe-separated field.

Comment: Maybe I am a bit too strict, the specs were not clear at all. My apologies.

Comment: ok fair point, updated further to address space in piped field as well

Comment: @kvantour the thing is, if the space-separated fields can't contain `|` and the `|`-separated fields can't contain spaces then we could just set FS to `[ |]` and we're done so we have to assume it's not that simple or the OP would've done it :-). So you're right to be "strict".

Comment: A minor point here: by using `$1=$2=$3=""` you redefine `$0` and all `FS` are replaced by `OFS`. This means that multiple blanks are replaced by a single blank.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach -

```
while read a b c d e; do
   IFS="|" read -a f <<< "$e"
   echo "$a $b $c ${f[3]} ${f[4]}"
done < input.txt
aaa bbb ccc hhh iii
aaa b|b|b ccc hhh "i i i"
aaa1 bbb1 ccc1 hhh1 iii1
aaa1 bbb1 c|c|c|1 hhh1 " i i i 1"
aaa2 bbb2 ccc2 hhh2 iii2
aaa2 bbb2 ccc2 "h h h 2" iii2
```

The read loads fields splitting on the usual `$IFS` characters, which puts all the last batch separated by pipes into `e`. This preserves any pipe characters embedded in `a`-`d`. Since `e` is the last variable, the rest of the line is stored there, even if it has embedded spaces.

`e` is split explicitly on pipes only into the array named `f`. This preserves any space characters embedded in the fields of `e`.

It's not much different from Charles' solution below, though.

Comment: yes, this solves it. Had the same solution a few seconds after you ;-)

Comment: lol -- I was wondering if I was just so slow that I didn't see this either. XD

Answer (score 1):

This will do exactly what you asked for regardless of whether fields in the head (space-separated) section contain `|`s or fields in the tail (`|`-separated) section contain spaces.

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and `\S/\s` shorthand:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/^((\S+\s+){3})(.*)/,a) {
    split(a[1],h,/\s+/)
    split(a[3],t,/[|]/)
    print h[1], h[2], h[3], t[4], t[5]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
aaa bbb ccc hhh iii
aaa1 bbb1 ccc1 hhh1 iii1
aaa2 bbb2 ccc2 hhh2 iii2
```

and with any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}/) {
    split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),h,/[[:space:]]+/)
    split(substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH),t,/[|]/)
    print h[1], h[2], h[3], t[4], t[5]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
aaa bbb ccc hhh iii
aaa1 bbb1 ccc1 hhh1 iii1
aaa2 bbb2 ccc2 hhh2 iii2
```

The above is assuming you're correct and it's only the first 3 fields that are separated by spaces, hence the `{3}` in the regexp. If you're mistaken and it's actually 4 (as it appears like it might be in your posted sample input) then obviously just change `{3}` to `{4}`. It will only matter if you want to access a 4th space-separated field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one `awk` solution. Too simple so I am not sure what edge cases I am missing but I get the desired output

```
awk -v FS="[ |]"  '{print $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $8 OFS $9}' inputFile
```

result

```
aaa bbb ccc hhh iii
aaa1 bbb1 ccc1 hhh1 iii1
aaa2 bbb2 ccc2 hhh2 iii2
```

Explanation:

I separated the fields with regex by either a space or a pipe `[ |]` and printed the asked fields.

Comment: The edge cases you're missing are where `|`s appear in the space-separated fields and/or spaces appear in the `|`-separated fields.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu awk:

```
awk -F'[ |]' '{print $1,$2,$3,$8,$9 } ' d
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="\\w{3,}"}{print $1,$2,$3,$8,$9 } ' d
```

the last is far better as far greater control on field search

Comment: Only the 2nd one requires GNU awk, the first will work in any awk.